# Show all available filters in list filter pane

Tags: list-view, filter

My company uses a SharePoint list to track projects as they are produced and shipped. This list has around 100 columns of data, but the default view has 20 columns visible. When we open the Filters Pane we are shown no more than 5 columns that we can filter by. On several occasions I have removed on of the options and SharePoint has popped another in, so I know it *can* show more than 5, and is just choosing which 5 I likely want to see.

How can I make it so that SharePoint gives the option to filter by every column possible in the Filters Pane, and not just 5 of them?

Comment: Are you wanting to fix the filter for a specific view or are you wanting to filter on the fly? Depending on your needs it might be easier to create a linked Excel file and use the more flexible filtering capabilities of Excel.

Comment: We're wanting to filter on the fly. The filter options already available are perfectly suitable, but as I stated in the question, SharePoint is simply not showing all of them. For example, we have the option to filter by the date we received paperwork and finalized the order, but not to filter by the date we actually received the initial order. SharePoint needs to provide access to all filters in the pane, not just 5 of them.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot to demonstrate the problem you are experiencing?